# C# string to double

Tags: c#, строки, double

Пытаюсь преобразовать строку "2,3" в double
получаю число 2.299999999999...

Использую Convert.ToDouble(string);

```
string value = "2,3"; // 2,3
double res = Convert.ToDouble(value); //2.299999999999...
```

Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Comment: в отдельном приложении бага нет, уверены, что структура идентична?

Comment: уверены, что double может хранить 2,3? попробуйте decimal

Comment: Если совсем все плохо(каким то образом) пробуйте ещё Double.Parse(value);

Comment: 2.3 представляется в виде double с погрешностью. используйте decimal.

Comment: double x = 2.3;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("2,3"));
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("2,3")); хотя, у меня этот код выводит 2,3 2,3 2,3